# Use of string.replace() in javascript to change content of a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I have a textarea with some text (suppose it says THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG). When I press a button, the content of the textarea changes to replace the word "BROWN" with another word (eg "RED")

```
<textarea id="text3" >THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG.</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="myFunction();"/>
<script type="application/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var textElem = document.getElementById("text3");
    var newText = textElem.replace("BROWN", "RED");
    newText = textElem.replace("FOX", "RABBIT");
    newText = textElem.replace("JUMPED", "LEAPED");
    newText = textElem.replace("LAZY", "SLEEPING");
    textElem.value = newText.value;
}
</script>
```

The code does not appear to work. I have tried seeing if the function was caling properly and whether variables were strings.

EDIT:
The function now reads:

```
function myFunction() {
    var textElem = document.getElementById("text3").value;
     newText = textElem.replace("BROWN", "RED");
     newText = textElem.replace("FOX", "RABBIT");
     newText = textElem.replace("JUMPED", "LEAPED");
     newText = textElem.replace("LAZY", "SLEEPING");
     alert(newText); /*I added this to see what the value of newText is*/
    textElem = newText;
}
```

Through the alert, I noticed that newText does not change from the original. Is there something wrong with the textElem.replace ?

Comment: use this instead: var textElem = document.getElementById("text3").value;

Comment: You are using the element itself instead of the text inside it. Use `var textElem = document.getElementById("text3").value;`.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing it incorrectly.

> The [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.
>   This method **does not change** the String object it is called on. It simply returns a new string.

Thus in your case you are always invoking this function on `textElem` which will not get affected and you end up getting the result of last replacement.

```
 var newText = textElem.replace("BROWN", "RED");//textElem is not changed
 newText = textElem.replace("FOX", "RABBIT");//textElem is not changed and hence you will not get the above replacement
```

Therefore You should invoke the **replace** method on newText and assign to itself like below

```
 var newText = textElem.replace("BROWN", "RED");
 newText = newText.replace("FOX", "RABBIT");//replace and assign to the same string
```

Comment: Also, last line, is not assigning the result back to `value` property.

Comment: Yes @Kami. Also no need to create another variable newText. One can keep replacing the textElem and at the end value to be assigned to textarea like document.getElementById("text3").value = replacedText. I omitted it to emphasize on replace method.

Answer (score 1):

you have set textElem as an object not a text value. You may use this code instead:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var textElem = document.getElementById("text3").value;
    var newText = textElem.replace("BROWN", "RED");
    newText = newText.replace("FOX", "RABBIT");
    newText = newText.replace("JUMPED", "LEAPED");
    newText = newText.replace("LAZY", "SLEEPING");
    document.getElementById("text3").value = newText;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Guffa said: you need to use the text of the element. Not the element itself.
The replace() function works on strings. So you have to save the text of the element in a variable. Then you can change the text. After all words are replaced, set the new text to the element.

```
function myFunction() {
        var textElem = document.getElementById("text3");
        var newText = textElem.value;
        newText = newText.replace("BROWN", "RED");
        newText = newText.replace("FOX", "RABBIT");
        newText = newText.replace("JUMPED", "LEAPED");
        newText = newText.replace("LAZY", "SLEEPING");

        textElem.value = newText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example replacing the text
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/StevenIseki/n82dr82h/)

As Ivan and Guffa mentioned you need to initially get the textElem using the textarea value **property**

```
var textElem = document.getElementById("text3").value
```

As Amitesh mentioned you need to invoke the replace **method** on newText rather than on the textElem variable.

```
function myFunction() {
    var textElem = document.getElementById("text3").value;
    var newText = textElem.replace("BROWN", "RED");
    newText = newText.replace("FOX", "RABBIT");
    newText = newText.replace("JUMPED", "LEAPED");
    newText = newText.replace("LAZY", "SLEEPING");
    document.getElementById("text3").value = newText;
}
```